# python: while loop does not reach last iteration

Tags: python, while-loop, iteration

I don't get the result of this code:

```
a = i = 0.05
b = 1.0
while a <= b:
  print a
  a += i
```

Of course this should print 0.05,0.1,...,1.0 but instead the iteration stops at 0.95. Is it a float issue?

Comment: Add a `print a` after the loop. And see the value. Issue with floats I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're working with floating point numbers, so you won't end up exactly at 1.0. Set b to e.g. 1.001 to cater for the rounding errors. Note that your numbers will be represented in binary. If they were truly decimal, they could be represented exactly.

By the way, I'd rather use:

```
for i in range (1, 21):
    print i/20.
```

Note that the . (or .0) behind the 20 makes it a float, forcing float division.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a better answer would be the following:

```
a = i = 0.05
b = 1.0
a = i = int(a * 1000)
b = int(b * 1000)
while a <= b:
   print a/1000.0
   a += i
```

This way you wont need to deal with floating point numbers at all. Many ways to skin a cat.